# Shiny - Plotly Time Series and dateRangeInput

Tags: r, date, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

I've got a Shiny dashboard with an Plotly time series, the range of which is adjusted via a reactive dateRangeInput I put together (please see code below).

Everything was working fine, but then I updated my packages. Since then, the variables do not automatically show in the first instance, you have to choose the date ranges instead of the plot loading in with a default time range.

What's more the dateRangeInput is using strange language such as monate, tueate, wedate etc.

I need some help to establish what my issue may be.

**Session info**

*Prior to the update* I was using Plotly 3.6.0, shinyDashboard 0.5.1 and shiny 0.13.2.

*After the update* I am using Plotly 4.5.6, shinyDashboard 0.5.3 and shiny 0.14.2

**Please see the respective code below**

ui - plotlyOuput Time Series code

```
box(width = 8, 
    solidHeader = TRUE, 
    plotlyOutput("Time_Ser", height ="300px"))
```

ui - dateRangeInput code

```
dateRangeInput("date","Date:", 
              label = h4("Time Series: select dates"),
              start = "2017-05-02",
              end = "2017-07-30", 
              min = "2017-05-02",
              max = "2017-06-30", 
              startview = "2017-06-30")
```

server - Reactive input code

```
        Time2 <- Time
                 reactiveTime <- reactive({
                 Time2 %>% filter(Date.received>=input$date[1] & 
                 Date.received<input$date[2])
                 })
```

server - output

```
       output$Time_Ser <- renderPlotly({
                          Time_Ser <- plot_ly(reactiveTime(), 
                          x = ~Date.received, 
                          y = ~n, 
                          type = "scatter", 
                          mode = "lines") %>%
                          layout(title = "Enquiries Time Series")
                          })
```

**Supporting images**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the following for your `dateRangeInput`.  I can't explain why your code worked before, but note that `startview` should be a categorical string, you can specify date format shown (to overwrite the fact that it seems to be defaulting to `DD`), and you can force language (but shouldn't actually need to).

```
dateRangeInput("date", "Date:", 
          label = h4("Time Series: select dates"),
          start = "2016-05-02",
          end = "2016-12-31",
          min = "2016-01-01",
          max = "2016-12-31",
          startview = "year",
          weekstart=0,
          language="en",
          format="yyyy-mm-dd")
```

- Note that the dates in the above apply to some dummy data I created for testing purposes.

Comment: unfortunately the plot is still not loading a default view of the data. However, the problem of the labels in the input has been solved by using the code you provided. Many thanks.